# Email forwarder to PHP

Tags: php, email, pipe, imap

I've been capturing the body of email messages with PHP using the following code:

```
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email_content = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
$email_content .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd)
```

So, the way its set up is mail is forwarded to the PHP script.

Works great when I send a email from a gmail account to the server email account. Message is forwared to the PHP, and PHP stores the body of the message to a variable.

But others have sent emails to my server containing HTML which doesn't work. Why wouldn't my code above be able to capture the contents of the email if it contains HTML?

Comment: No way to tell. The snippet by itself wouldn't stumble over HTML. (One could shorten it to just `$str = file_get_contents("php://stdin");` however). So your "doesn't work" issue lies somewhere else.

Comment: @mario you'r right. it doesn't work with any emails lol. (sorry, it stopped working just as html email were sent.) not sure what changed on the server for it to suddenly stop working. i have code directly below what i posted that sends an email to me displaying the variables value. but im not getting any email now